# DolphinDB: concatenate date and time

Tags: sql, timestamp, dolphindb, temporal

The following two columns are of DATETIME and SECOND data type, respectively.

```
ActionDay           minute
2023.01.31T18:47:20 00:00:05
2023.01.31T18:47:20 00:00:05
2023.01.31T18:47:20 00:00:01
2023.01.31T18:47:20 00:00:01
2023.01.31T18:47:20 00:00:06
```

Now I want to create a column of TIMESTAMP type based on these two columns. How can I do with SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you actually want because DATETIME type already has second part. It's an example for adding-up DATETIME and SECOND:

```
select timestamp(ActionDay + minute) from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Convert column “minute“ (of SECOND type) to INT type, and add to column “ActionDay“ (of DATETIME type).

```
select ActionDay + minute.int() from T
```

Solution 2:

Create a new column by adding column “ActionDay“  and “minute“, and then convert it to DATETIME type. Both `datetime()` and `cast(`, datetime)` can be used:

```
select datetime(ActionDay+minute)  from T

select cast(ActionDay+minute, DATETIME) as dt from T
```

Solution 3:

Use the `concatDateTime()` function to combine the date of olumn “ActionDay“ with “minute“:

```
select concatDateTime(date(ActionDay),minute) from T
```

I test the above three methods on an in-memory table with 10 million records.

```
n=10000000
T = table(take(2023.01.10T00:00:00 2023.01.10T00:00:00,n) as `ActionDay, take(15:00:00 15:19:00 ,n) as `minute);
timer select cast(ActionDay+minute, DATETIME) as dt from T
timer select concatDateTime(date(ActionDay),minute) from T
timer select ActionDay + minute.int() from T
timer select datetime(ActionDay+minute)  from T
```

The results are as follows:

```
Time elapsed: 19.946 ms

Time elapsed: 16.956 ms

Time elapsed: 10.971 ms

Time elapsed: 9.973 ms
```

It can be seen from the result that the solution 1 (9.973 ms) and solution 2 using `datetime()` (10.971 ms) are relatively quicker.